# Execute PHP code when making a post in a cms

Tags: php

Sorry for the vague title but it's hard to describe what I mean in a few words.

I made my own cms and use it for all my personal projects. On some pages I want to include a php script in the content area. I load the content simply by echoing the variable that holds the content.

The template file looks like this:

```
<div id="content">
echo $content;
</div>
```

In my CRUD I make a post containing a php snippet.

```
<?php echo "My name is ".$var.""; ?>;
```

Then I save it and load the page and this is what happens:

```
<div id="content">
echo <?php echo "My name is ".$var.""; ?>;
</div>
```

But what I want is that the php code get's executed instead of getting echoed. 
Something like the Wordpress plugin Exec-PHP. Can anybody explain to me how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [PHP eval() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to execute PHP code. Be aware though, if you ever allow users to insert text that may at some point be run through `eval()`, you could end up with some serious problems.

The php website says:

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
>   execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you
>   have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this
>   construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data
>   into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You can try php [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) func. But it is considered evil.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use PHP instructions, why don't you output to HTML, and use Javascript to execute what is displayed?  There is no danger to your server that way.  Others have already warned about the dangers of `eval()` in PHP.